# Search Engine/Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to make a search engine but i Got this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: construct in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\search.php on line 24.
```

im trying to display the results and show the pagination.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 
$x = 0;

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","test");
mysql_select_db("test");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
```

i dont know why is it undefined.

this is my Line 24: `$construct .= " username LIKE '%$search_each%'";`

```
else
$construct .= " AND details_in LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM intime WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that warning because you are using `.=` which is used to append.

```
$construct .= " username LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

You haven't defined `$construct` previously but you are trying to append a string to it, hence the warning. You should define `$construct` before you use it. For example:

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 
$x = 0;
$construct = ''; // Defined construct here

//
// .. rest of your code
//
```

Comment: it works like a charm! Thank you Sir Jonathon. i will make this an answer when i get my +15 rep.